# How to add element components from in and out of promise

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, for-loop, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an image with it's source set to a download url which is retrieved by a `.getDownloadURL()` function from firebase.

I also want to set the id of the image to the firebase storage path, so I can get the name of the image.

The issue however, is that when I try to make the path inside the `.getDownloadURL()` function, it says *"can't get location of undefined"*, because the scope of the path variable doesn't reach inside.

My attempt at a solution was to create the image and add the id before entering the `.getDownloadUrl()` function, but then I can't set the `.src` of img inside of the 'getDownloadURL()' function because img is undefined.

Anyway I would appreciate any help, thanks for your time.

Here is my code:

```
for(n=0; n<subarray.length; n++){
    //add image with url src
    var path = subarray[n].location.path_; //I want the img ID to be this
    var img = document.createElement("IMG"); //this is the IMG
    img.id = path;


    storage.ref(subarray[n].location.path_).getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
        img.src = url; //error says cannot set .src of undefined
        column = "column" + columnNr //columnNr is defined earlier as 1
        columnNr = columnNr + 1;
        if(columnNr > 4){
            columnNr = 1;
        }


         document.getElementById(column).appendChild(img);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you get an error "cannot set .src of undefined" with the code of your question?  Normally, variables defined in the parent function can be accessed through the child scope and `img` shall be accessible in the callback function. If the error is "can't get location of undefined", it means `subarray[n]` is undefined.

Comment: yeah that is the problem, I need to find a way to pass subarray[n] into the function, if possible

Comment: You need to share more code, in particular what is around this code. How do you get `subarray[n]`? What it is? It seems undefined and therefore you should check its value.